# Iterating through ADODB Fields inside a Recordset loop

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba, ado

I am attempting to create a function that takes an ADODB Recordset and copies its data into a new recordset.

To do this, I use a **do** loop to move through each row of a source recordset. Inside that do loop, I need to use **for each** loop to move through each row's Fields collection, to capture its data.

However, VB6 seems to choke on the *for each* loop - it highlights the name of the for loop
s iterator ("fld" in the example below) and throws a **variable not defined** error.

Oddly, the exact same for each loop works just fine when not placed inside a *do* loop.

**Test case 1 *(unable to define "For Each fld")*:**

'targetTableName As String: name of new table to create
'sourceRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset: open recordset containing the results to publish to the new targetTableName

```
Public Sub createTableFromRecordset(targetTableName As String, sourceRecordSet As ADODB.recordSet)
        '(irrelevant code omitted)

        'create MDB RS object
        Dim targetRecordSet As ADODB.recordSet
        Set targetRecordSet = mdbQuery("select * from targetTableName;")

        'write data to recordset
        sourceRecordSet.MoveFirst ' to be safe
        targetRecordSet.MoveFirst ' to be safe
        While Not sourceRecordSet.EOF
            targetRecordSet.AddNew
            For Each fld In sourceRecordSet.Fields 'fails here, hilighting fld
                'do work
            Next fld
            sourceRecordSet.MoveNext
        Loop

        '(irrelevant code omitted)            

End Sub
```

**Test case 2 *(able to define "For Each fld" just fine)*:**

```
Private Sub testCase2()
    'Create a source dataset
    Dim sourceRs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set sourceRs = functionThatGetsRecordset("(a query)")

    'Create target db conn
    Dim mdbConn As ADODB.Connection
    Set mdbConn = functionThatGetsConn()

   'iterate through source's fields
    For Each fld In sourceRs.Fields 'works fine
        'do work 
    Next fld
End Sub
```

Comment: Same issue. I just called it "Field" to remove the business name in the actual unit - I will rename in the examples

Comment: RE the latest revision of your question, do you have `Dim fld As ADODB.Field` somewhere?

Comment: No, there is no explicitely defined *fld* in either case.

Comment: And what happens if you add `Dim fld As ADODB.Field`?

Comment: Works as expected. Apologies, this is unlike for next behavior in other languages I've used.

Submit that as an answer below and collect your sweet sweet karma :)

Comment: Heh, sorry gents, submitted my answer after I got coffee so I missed the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try two things:

1. Use a different variable name just to be safe. "Field" is the name of a type, and has the potential to confuse both you and VBA.  Instead, I would suggest using "fldField" or "tempField" or some such.
2. Right before the "For Each" lines, create the loop variable by Dimming it:

`Dim fldField As Field`

Comment: Funny, if I add just that one line (and update the `For Each` statement): `Dim fldField As Field`, I get `Expected end of statement` as an error.